# VS2010 When debugging web.config transforms are not being applied. Building a deployment package works

Tags: visual-studio-2010, web-config

When I debug a web application, the web.config transforms are not applied.
I simply find that the configuration in web.config is not applying the transform for the configuration I'm currently using.

Yet if I build a deployment package then I find that the web.config does have the current transforms applied.

Are transforms not applied when debugging? I'm starting to wonder if this is the case, but I have coworkers insisting that it works for them.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Web.config transforms are only applied when publishing or deploying.

Jared Harding provided a link where a member of the .NET Team answered this question in the response here: [VS2010 Clean Web.configs - not updating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2634240/vs2010-clean-web-configs-not-updating)

The link he provided for ease of reference is: http://forums.asp.net/p/1532038/3711423.aspx

Comment: Thanks I appreciate the response. I searched Google high and low for a definitive answer to this. I shall now attempt to guilt my coworkers into doughnuts or something. Perhaps just dish out a noogie.

Comment: I'm trying to find the link that more clearly says this, if I find it I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can start a transform by introducing a "AfterBuild" entry in your project file as described here.
Downside: you have 2 web.config files...

http://kfigy.blogspot.ch/2010/03/making-visual-studio-2010-webconfig.html

Comment: If After Build doesn't help, try Before Build.