# Apply web.config transforms whilst debugging in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, web-config, transform, replace

I have a mvc4 project which has four solution configurations and a transform web.config file for each. I need to be able to change config and have the transforms applied so I can debug in Visual Studio 2010.

I can do this easily with console applications as they are compiled into a bin folder and the configs applied but unfortunately not with the mvc app.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I think this post answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6300205/vs2010-when-debugging-web-config-transforms-are-not-being-applied-building-a-de